# Change state if I choose other React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to display the props value from the react router in the {title} place but I do not know if it is possible.

If router`'/dashboard'`, `{title}` = 'Dashboard',
Else if router `'/payment'`, `{title}` = 'Payment'

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
  };

  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;

  return (
     <Typography>
         {title}
     </Typography>

  <Switch>
    <Route title="Dashboard" exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
    <Route title="Payment" path="/payment" component={PaymentPage} />
  </Switch>
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1: You can wrap your Header component with withRouter which provides location as prop which has pathname inside it. You can use that to change title.

Method 2: you pass a function as prop to DashboardPage which will set state of title in Header component.

In Header component:

```
_setTitle = (title) => this.setState({ title })
```

Pass _setTitle as below

```
<Route
  path='/dashboard'
  exact
  render={(props) => <DashboardPage {...props} setTitle={this._setTitle} />}
/>
```

In DashboardPage component's constructor execute setTitle to set the correct title as below:

```
class DashboardPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.props.setTitle('Dashboard');
    }
}
```

Do the same for PaymentPage.

This should work. Let me know if this solves your problem.